# How to staple Apple notarization tickets manually (e.g. under linux)

Tags: python, linux, macos, code-signing, notarize

Recently (as of 2023-11-01) Apple has changed their notarization process.

I took the opportunity to drop Apple's own tools for this process (`notarytool`) and switch to a Python-based solution using their [documented Web API for notarization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notaryapi/submitting_software_for_notarization_over_the_web)

This works great and has the additional bonus, that I can now notarize macOS apps from linux (in the context of CI, I can provision linux runners much faster than macOS runners). hooray.

Since this went so smooth, I thought about moving more parts of my codesigning process to linux, and the obvious next step is find a solution for stapling the notarization tickets into application, replacing `xcrun stapler staple MyApp.app`

With the help of `-vv` and some scraps of [online](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3126-inside-code-signing-hashes) [documentation](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/logging-https.html), it turns out that it is very simple to obtain the notarization ticket if you know the code directory hash (`CDhash`) of your application.

the following will return a JSON-object containing (among other things) the base64-encoded  notarization ticket, which just has to be decoded and copied into the .app bundle for stapling:

```bash
cdhash=8d817db79d5c07d0deb7daf4908405f6a37c34b4
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   --data "{ \"records\": { \"recordName\": \"2/2/${cdhash}\" }}" \
   https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/com.apple.gk.ticket-delivery/production/public/records/lookup \
| jq -r ".records[0] | .fields | .signedTicket | .value"
```

So, the only thing that is still missing for my `stapler` replacement is a way to obtain the code directory hash for a given application.
On macOS (with the XCode tools installed), I can get this hash with `codesign -d -vvv MyApp.app`, but this obviously only works if I have the `codesign` binary at hand.

I've found a couple of python wrappers for stapling tickets, but all of them just call `xcrun stapler staple` under the hood.
This is **not what I want**.

So my question is:
How can I extract the code directory hash (`CDhash`) from a macOS application, *without* using macOS specific tools? (That is: How are `CDhash`es generated? I haven't found any documentation on this)

I would very much like to use use Python for this task.
Ideally, such a solution would be cross-platform (so I can use it on macOS *and* Linux, and probably others as well).

Comment: Have you tried just making a SHA-256 hash of a tar of the directory, or any experiments like that to see if it produces the right value?

Comment: lxop not really, but i did strip away files from the app-bundle and could still extract the same CDhash with `stapler validate`, so it obviously cannot be the *entire* app. otoh, tar-files encode ownership and modification dates of files as well as the file order (`tar c A B` produces a different file from `tar c B A`) i don't really see how to create a reproducible tar-archive to create a reproducible SHA-256 from there.

Comment: to the downvoters: i'm really looking for a way to implement a notarization ticket stapler, and as such a i think that my question is valid for [so]. i'm explicitly **not** looking for a tool (like Apples's `stapler`) that already does this, but i want to do it myself.

Comment: but i see that my "with (Open Source) tools that are available on other platforms, esp. linux" can be read as "looking for a tool".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I extract the code directory hash (CDhash) from a macOS
> application, without using macOS specific tools?

The CDhash of an app is the CDhash of the main executable in Contents/MacOS as identified in Contents/Info.plist

Each hash is stored at the end of the binary segment for each architecture in an XML statement. It can be grepped out.

The embedded cdhash is encoded in base64.  The first one is for intel, the second for apple silicon:

```
% grep -i -a -A3 'cdhashes' myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/mainexec | sed -n '4p;9p' | cut -f 3  
HPhKLQv1j2SFYTmIgyUi/L6B9Yo=
TVNDrCQEL9A/DMWVmphntZAq7kc=

% printf "HPhKLQv1j2SFYTmIgyUi/L6B9Yo=" | base64 -d | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x" ' && echo ""
1cf84a2d0bf58f6485613988832522fcbe81f58a

% printf "TVNDrCQEL9A/DMWVmphntZAq7kc=" | base64 -d | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x" ' && echo ""
4d5343ac24042fd03f0cc5959a9867b5902aee47
```

Compared with the cdhash as reported by codesign:

```
% codesign -dvvv -a arm64 myApp.app
Executable=myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/mainexec
Identifier=com.mycompany.myApp
Format=app bundle with Mach-O universal (x86_64 arm64)
CodeDirectory v=20500 size=92199 flags=0x10000(runtime) hashes=2870+7 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=4d5343ac24042fd03f0cc5959a9867b5902aee47
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=4d5343ac24042fd03f0cc5959a9867b5902aee4725c5a75775cd711aae76b709
Hash choices=sha256
CMSDigest=4d5343ac24042fd03f0cc5959a9867b5902aee4725c5a75775cd711aae76b709
CMSDigestType=2
Launch Constraints:
    None
CDHash=4d5343ac24042fd03f0cc5959a9867b5902aee47
```

Comment: that goes in the right direction; unfortunately my app has multiple cdhashes (i have two sections both containing something like `<key>cdhashes</key><array><data>12345</data><data>abcde</data></array>`); most likely this is due to frameworks being included in the app. is there any rule which cdhash to pick?

Comment: Each hashed codepage should correspond with a calculable offset entry in the `otool -l`, finding each hash at the end of each page in the binary.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706419

Comment: Don’t pack the main binary with libraries. Keep them dynamically linked.

Comment: the application comes with two frameworks (Tcl & Tk) included in the `.app` bundle, but it is dynamically linking to these frameworks. Tcl/Tk is patched, we don't really won't to install them systemwide (and we cannot use the frameworks bundled with macOS, because these are just outdated and buggy). i'm not exactly sure where the additional cdhashes come from these included frameworks, it was just a wild guess (most likely a wrong one, as there are 2 frameworks but only 1 additional cdhash per architecture)

Answer (score 0):

based on [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77459873/1169096), this is what I've ended up using (with a lot more error checking):

```py
import base64
import re
import plistlib

import requests

def extractEmbeddedPlists(filename):
    """extract embedded plist data sections from binary file"""
    # this is a very crude way to do it!
    # LATER properly parse the macho file (with something like 'macholibre')
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
    try:
        return [
            plistlib.loads(_)
            for _ in re.findall(b"<plist.*?</plist>", data, flags=re.DOTALL)
        ]
    except:
        pass
    return []


def getCDHashes(app):
    """get code directory hashes from a bundle
    not all cdhashes might be valid!
    """
    info_plist = os.path.join(app, "Contents", "Info.plist")
    try:
        with open(info_plist, "rb") as f:
            info = plistlib.load(f)
    except:
        return []
    if "CFBundleExecutable" not in info:
        return []
    plists = extractEmbeddedPlists(os.path.join(app, "Contents", "MacOS", info["CFBundleExecutable"]))
    cdhashes = [_["cdhashes"] for _ in plists if "cdhashes" in _]
    hashes = {_.hex() for a in cdhashes for _ in a}
    return hashes

def getTicket(cdhash):
    """retrieve a notarization ticket for a given cdhash"""
    recordName = "2/2/%s" % cdhash
    data = {
        "records": {"recordName": recordName},
    }
    r = requests.post(ticket_url, json=data)

    j = r.json()
    record = j["records"][0]
    if record.get("serverErrorCode") == "NOT_FOUND":
        return

    ticket = record["fields"]["signedTicket"]["value"]
    return base64.b64decode(ticket)

def getTicket(app):
    for hash in getCDHashes(app):
        try:
            ticket = getTicket(hash)
            if ticket: return ticket
        except: pass
```

there are still some rough edges that are not handled yet (e.g. deciding which ticket to staple if the binary contains multiple CDHashes (one for each architecture of a universal binary) that yield different tickets), but the basics are now working.